# Permission denied copying files from an old HDD drive

Tags: permissions, ownership

I think this might be because I am not the owner.
I have opened the folder as administrator and can view all the files but can't copy them because of the permissions.
The old HDD is in a caddy connected by USB.
I think I might have to recursively change owner of all sub folders in terminal?

Comment: why don't you provide what you've tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked it out.

```
sudo chown [new-owner] -R [folder]
```

-R does it recursively to all subfolders.
Phew!